# How to use unpack with codecs

Tags: python, codec, unpack

I am trying to run python script written in pre 3.5 version and when I run it I get error so I am trying to update the function, but still can not figure out the problem.
Here is my code:

```
# Main message decoding routine
# Input: diameter message as HEX string
# Result: class H with splitted message (header+message)
# AVPs in message are NOT splitted
def stripHdr(H,msg):
    dbg = "Incoming Diameter msg",msg
    logging.info(dbg)
    if len(msg) == 0:
        return ERROR
    (sver,msg) = chop_msg(msg,2)
    (slen,msg) = chop_msg(msg,6)
    (sflag,msg) = chop_msg(msg,2)
    (scode,msg) = chop_msg(msg,6)
    (sapp,msg) = chop_msg(msg,8)
    (shbh,msg) = chop_msg(msg,8)
    (sete,msg) = chop_msg(msg,8)
    dbg = "Split hdr", "V", sver, "L", slen, "F", sflag, "C", scode, "A", sapp, "H", shbh, "E", sete, "D", msg
    logging.debug(dbg)
    #H.ver = ord(sver.decode("hex"))
    H.ver = ord(codecs.decode(sver, 'hex'))
    H.flags = ord(codecs.decode(sflag,'hex'))
    #H.len = struct.unpack("!I","\00"+slen.decode("hex"))[0]
    H.len = struct.unpack("!I","\00"+codecs.decode(slen, 'hex'))[0]
    H.cmd = struct.unpack("!I","\00"+scode.decode("hex"))[0]
    H.appId = struct.unpack("!I",sapp.decode("hex"))[0]
    H.HopByHop = struct.unpack("!I",shbh.decode("hex"))[0]
    H.EndToEnd = struct.unpack("!I",sete.decode("hex"))[0]
    dbg="Read", "V", H.ver, "L", H.len, "F", H.flags, "C", H.cmd, "A", H.appId, "H", H.HopByHop, "E", H.EndToEnd
    logging.debug(dbg)
    dbg = dictCOMMANDcode2name(H.flags,H.cmd)
    logging.info(dbg)
    H.msg = msg
    return
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  File "diameter-client.py", line 306, in <module>
    stripHdr(CEA, codecs.encode(received, encoding="hex"))
  File "/home/centos/pyprotosim_python3-master/libDiameter.py", line 786, in stripHdr
    H.len = struct.unpack("!I","\00"+codecs.decode(slen, 'hex'))[0]
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you much!

Comment: By pre 3.5 do you mean python 3-3.4  or python < 3.0

Comment: This is SO not the right way to handle this task.  I want to rewrite it, but it's not my job.  In the short term, you should be able to achieve your goal by changing `"\00"` to `b"\00"` in those two `unpack` calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thanks Tim, b"\00" worked!